# listview in a viewpager based on fragments

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm using a viewpager based on fragments, and it works amazingly. My viewpager shows a button on each page (since it's what I put in the layout xml file of each fragment).
Now I want to have a listview with different data on each page instead of the buttons. And that's why in the first place I opted to use fragments. 
The problem is that I didn't find a way to integrate listviews in my viewpager.
Any ideas please?

Here is my code :

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentA.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentB.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentC.class.getName()));
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        pager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }
}
```

main.xml declaring the viewpager

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;
    private static String[] titles = new String[] {"A", "B", "C"};

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPageTitle( int position )
    {
        return titles[ position ];
    }
}
```

FragmentA.java

```
    public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    }
}
```

fragment_a.xml only contains a button

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button android:text="@string/a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ListFragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) and [the official ListView tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html). The tutorial uses a ListActivity, but you can essentially substitute it with a ListFragment.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try working with ListFragments instead of Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace your button in xml with a ListView (or keep both).

In your fragment class, create an arrayAdapter and set it to the list view

```
mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_list);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

You can create a custom adapter and set whatever you need in getView function